# Spark SQL Java: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark

I am reading a table. One of the columns contains compressed (binary)data. I'm uncompressing this data and storing in another RDD. It gives the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job
>   aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most
>   recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor
>   driver): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Exception:
>   failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException:
>   File 'generated.java', Line 36, Column 31: A method named "toString"
>   is not declared in any enclosing class nor any supertype, nor through
>   a static import

Code:

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark  .read()  .format("jdbc")  .options(options)  
.load().limit(10);

JavaRDD<ConfigObject> 
configObjs=df.as(Encoders.bean(ConfigObject.class)).javaRDD();

JavaRDD<ConfigObjectResult> configObjsResult=configObjs.map(obj -> {
ConfigObjectResult confObjRes= new ConfigObjectResult();
confObjRes.setConfigID(obj.getConfigID());
confObjRes.setAgentVersion(obj.getAgentVersion());
confObjRes.setUncompressedDoc(Compressor.getInstance().
unCompressData(obj.getCompressedDoc()));
confObjRes.setCreationDate(obj.getCreationDate());
    return  confObjRes;
});
```

Comment: Are you using @Generated in your ConfigObject class?

Comment: no I am not using

Answer (score 1):

CreationDate is a time stamp in Database . Same is a String in my Obj. After converting the time stamp to String , it worked.